# How to create folders from one hot encoding csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, data-science

I am working on skin cancer classification, I have "GroundTruth.csv" file and "training data" as jpg images, the csv file in one hot encoding format and I want to put the images into folders with the columns as folders name.

this image clear the meaning

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/45392637/57570855-0a6cb400-7407-11e9-8eb3-adb7b1bd70b6.JPG

```
# Create new folders in the training directory for each of the classes
nv = os.path.join(train_dir, 'nv')
os.mkdir(nv)
mel = os.path.join(train_dir, 'mel')
os.mkdir(mel)
bkl = os.path.join(train_dir, 'bkl')
os.mkdir(bkl)
bcc = os.path.join(train_dir, 'bcc')
os.mkdir(bcc)
akiec = os.path.join(train_dir, 'akiec')
os.mkdir(akiec)
vasc = os.path.join(train_dir, 'vasc')
os.mkdir(vasc)
df = os.path.join(train_dir, 'df')
os.mkdir(df)

# Create new folders in the validation directory for each of the classes
nv = os.path.join(val_dir, 'nv')
os.mkdir(nv)
mel = os.path.join(val_dir, 'mel')
os.mkdir(mel)
bkl = os.path.join(val_dir, 'bkl')
os.mkdir(bkl)
bcc = os.path.join(val_dir, 'bcc')
os.mkdir(bcc)
akiec = os.path.join(val_dir, 'akiec')
os.mkdir(akiec)
vasc = os.path.join(val_dir, 'vasc')
os.mkdir(vasc)
df = os.path.join(val_dir, 'df')
os.mkdir(df)
```

**I want to put the images into the folders as my next step.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated as per edited question and additional information in the comments:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

# Read in the data
ground_truth = pd.read_csv('GroundTruth.csv')

# Loop through the DataFrame created from the csv file
for row in ground_truth.iterrows():
    image_name = row[1].image

    # Skip the first column, which is not one hot encoded
    target_folder = row[1].index[row[1].values[1:].argmax() + 1]
    if not os.path.exists(target_folder):
        # Create the folder
        os.makedirs(target_folder)
    # Move the file
    os.rename(f'./{image_name}.jpg',
              f'./{target_folder}/{image_name}.jpg')
```

Comment: how to put the images in the folders according to csv file information, that is the problem I get, sorry if the question was not clear but the code you post i already write it.

Comment: OK, no problem, I can update my anwer.  Are the images in the same folder as the csv file? And the names as per the first column in the csv file?

Comment: the csv file is with a folder named Inputs that contain the images.

Comment: @GuissousAllaeddine – see my updated answer.  I've not been able to test the code as I don't have suitable data to hand, but it should (hopefully!) work.  Let me know if you have any problems.

Comment: error occured

SyntaxError: f-string: single '}' is not allowed

Comment: Yep, sorry, I spotted that a couple of hours ago and fixed the code.  Try it as it's written now.

Comment: sorry but I am a newbie to the field and an other error : 

TypeError: reduction operation 'argmax' not allowed for this dtype

Comment: here is a colab notebook it public see the full code the:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ilH5H0xi9U3Y29lRNovEvz07euScHw6i

Comment: @GuissousAllaeddine apologies, I'd gone out. I'm home now and think I've fixed the problem in the colab notebook (the image download was corrupted and wouldn't unzip properly, so I couldn't test it fully).  Have a look and let me know how you get on.